# "Waiting for your editor to close the file" when trying to use Sublime Text 3 as Git editor

Tags: macos, text-editor, git, sublimetext

I'm trying to use Sublime Text 3 as Git's editor.

I ran this:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Then this:

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

I then ran:

```
git commit --amend
```

Sublime opened and I edited the file, saved it, and then closed it. However, Git was still waiting for the file to close:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
```

- There is no error message.
- I can use Sublime with no problems outside of Git.
- I tried restarting the machine (MacBook Pro).
- Using `textedit` works as expected: `git config --global core.editor "open -W -n"`
- The version of Sublime is: `3.2.1 Build 3207`
- Git: `git version 2.17.1 (Apple Git-112)`

Why isn't this working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376335/how-can-i-finish-editing-a-commit-message-with-sublime-text#comment68006558_40376508 This comment(year 2016) here by a similar problem says that all of sublime needs to be quit, not only that file, despite `-w -n` being used. This sure poses a problem with those using the app for the project also. I use textedit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50184996/git-editor-commit-error/50185115#50185115 Actually there are some more questions and answer for the same on SO too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951275/how-can-i-make-sublime-text-the-default-editor-for-git#comment34434278_9408117

Comment: @ankii I already use Cmd+Q to quit the editor, so unfortunately that doesn't help. The first link (using just `-w`) doesn't help, and I've already tried the second. Colleagues with the exact same Sublime version got it to work, so there's something really weird going on on my machine...